# Bash: Copy Contents of Log File to another file just-in-time / simultaneously

Tags: bash, file, logging

I have to use an application, which is logging to a fixed file ("foo.log"). However, I have to produce my own log file, enriched additional information ("bar.log"). Hence, I need to copy the contents of foo.log to bar.log.

The easiest approach would be to wait for the application to finish and then simply copy / cat contents from foo.log to bar.log. However, is there a way to copy contents from foo.log to bar.log just-in-time, i.e. whenever a new line was written to foo.log?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit the application? Or can you only 'view' the application, and have to make workarounds?

Comment: Use `tail -c +0 -f foo.log`

Comment: I cannot edit the application. It is clamd and it cannot be configured to write its output to a specific file other than the hardcoded one.

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
tail -f -c +0 foo.log
```

or

```
while read -r line ;do
     # do something with "$line"
   done < <(tail -f -c +0 foo.log)
```

or better

```
exec {logfile}< <(tail -f -c +0 foo.log)
while :; do
    while read -t 0 -u $logfile _ &&
          read -u $logfile line ;do
        echo do something with $line
    done
    read -sn1 -t .2 -r key && break
done
```

If you hit any key, loop will exit, but you could re-run loop (without `exec` step), then follow rest of log from last interrupt.

```
followLogFile() {
    while :; do
        while read -t 0 -u $logfile _ &&
              read -u $logfile line ;do
            echo do something with $line
        done
        read -sn1 -t .2 -r key && break
    done
}
```

#### Sample

First open another window, then hit:

```
cd $(mktemp -d)
pwd
msgs=(foo bar baz)
while :;do
    echo $((i++)) ${msgs[RANDOM%3]}
    sleep $((RANDOM%2)).$RANDOM
done >foo.log
```

Then is 1st window (with answer of `pwd` into `$tempDir`):

```
followLogFile() {
    while :; do
        while read -t 0 -u $logfile _ &&
              read -u $logfile line ;do
            case $line in
                *foo* ) echo "Foo found in log: '$line'" ;;
                * ) echo "Doing something else with '$line'" ;;
            esac
        done
        read -sn1 -t .2 -r key && break
    done
}

exec {logfile}< <(tail -f -c +0 $tempDir/foo.log)

followLogFile
```

could produce somehing like

```
Doing something else with '0 baz'
Doing something else with '1 bar'
Doing something else with '2 bar'
Foo found in log: '3 foo'
Doing something else with '4 bar'
Doing something else with '5 baz'
Doing something else with '6 bar'
Doing something else with '7 bar'
Doing something else with '8 bar'
Foo found in log: '9 foo'
Doing something else with '10 bar'
Doing something else with '11 bar'
Doing something else with '12 bar'
Foo found in log: '13 foo'
```

Then if you hit any key, this will stop, but if you

```
followLogFile
```

This will **continue**:

```
Foo found in log: '14 foo'
Foo found in log: '15 foo'
Foo found in log: '16 foo'
Doing something else with '17 bar'
Doing something else with '18 baz'
Foo found in log: '19 foo'
```

...

### Closing *`$logfile`*

Once done, you could:

```
exec {logfile}<&-
```

But this will be done when your script exit.